Selenium verision 4 using python behave to connect SeeTest
I am trying to run my desktop browser tests on seetest, I am using selenium 4 which has no desired capabilities but it uses 'options' however I tried multiple syntax but no use.. tests still connects to seetest and it always in Queue and then timeout.. could some suggest environments.py syntax for the same how to connect and run python bdd tests
